# Is it possible to stop (cancel) urlretrieve process?

Tags: python, urlretrieve

```
urlretrieve(URL, file_path, self.reporthook)
```

I use tkinter for Python 3 and want to abort downloading a file and close the application when user press close button.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I think that your best bet would be to look into [Tkinter threading & events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596975/terminate-the-thread-by-using-button-in-tkinter).

Answer (score 1):

You should look into multiprocessing. May not be what it was intended to do, but it should be possible to kill off outside of the code thread.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html