# Starting and stopping thread with python and tkinter

Tags: tkinter, event-handling, python-multithreading, python-3.8

I've been trying to use the code provided from this answer:

[Terminate the Thread by using button in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596975/terminate-the-thread-by-using-button-in-tkinter#new-answer?newreg=9ab00967dab34ccda9ccebb1820eea64)

But everytime I run it I end up with the following error messages when I click the buttons:

self.stop_threads.clear()
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'clear'

self.stop_threads.set()
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'set'

I know this has to be something simple but I'm well and truly stumped any advice/pointers would be appreciated.

```
from threading import Thread,Event
from subprocess import call
from tkinter import *

import tkinter as tk

class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread1 = None
        self.thread2 = None
        self.stop_threads = Event()

    def loop1(self):
        while not self.stop_threads.is_set():
            call(print('Thread Loop 1'))

    def loop2(self):
        while not self.stop_threads.is_set():
            call(print('Thread Loop 2'))

    def combine(self):
        self.stop_threads.clear()
        self.thread1 = Thread(target = self.loop1)
        self.thread2 = Thread(target = self.loop2)
        self.thread1.start()
        self.thread2.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_threads.set()
        self.thread1.join()
        self.thread2.join()
        self.thread1 = None
        self.thread2 = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = tk.Tk()
    master.title("Thread Start Stop Exercise")
    master.geometry("1024x600")

    control = Controller()

    btn1 = Button(master, text="Start Thread", width=16, height=5, command=control.combine)
    btn1.grid(row=2,column=0)
    btn2 = Button(master, text="Stop Thread", width=16, height=5, command=control.stop)
    btn2.grid(row=3,column=0)

    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Actually you are using `tkinter.Event`, not `threading.Event` because the line `from tkinter import *` is after `from threading import Thread, Event`. Swap the two lines.  `from tkinter import *` is not a good practice to import tkinter.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I knew it was something stupid I'd done! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `tkinter` also has a `tkinter.Event` object which is being used instead of `threading.Event` since `tkinter` is being imported after `threading`.

You can try swapping the lines:

```py
from subprocess import call
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread,Event
```

Or, be specific with the imports you need from `tkinter` or don't use a wildcard import at all to avoid global namespace pollution and errors like this. Prefix all the commands with `tk` and it will make the code completely obvious when you are using Tkinter classes, ttk classes, or others leaving no room for ambiguity.